# SSRS ReportServer list all reports located in a folder (recursive)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I would like to generate a list of all of the reports located in a folder in the `ReportServer` database from the `[dbo].[Catalog]` table.

I would like to include any report that may be listed in any child folders as well.

```
-Root
-Report: Three
-Folder: Demo
   + Report: One
   - SubFolder: Sample
      + Report: Two
```

In this Example if I selected all reports from `Folder: Demo` I would get back `Report: One` and `Report: Two` only.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just search for that particular folder in the `Path` column?

```
declare @folder varchar(256) = 'Demo'

select Name
from Catalog
where Path + '/' = '/' + @folder + '/'
```

By adding */* to `Path` and the variable you eliminate partial matches.

It might not be perfect where there are multiple folders with the same names in the folder structure but any method will have similar issues to overcome.

Comment: I've thought about doing this as a last resort since there is a chance that it could broken by someone adding a folder with the same name elsewhere. I started looking into CTE's to recursively build the tree but I'm not having any luck yet.